# Create a dummy image for each existing in directories?

Tags: php, image, watermark

I'm a bit stumped on a random personal project I'm working on.

I have a a directory (with subdirectories) filled with 100s of images of various sizes. I need to duplicate each image, black out the copy and save it alongside the existing image, adding a suffix like _copy.xxx.

Is there an existing watermarking script I could modify to do something like this? I'm just not sure if something like this exists but under another name, I may be searching the wrong terms.

Thank you for looking or for any suggestions, I really do appreciate it.

Comment: copy to autogenerated name file ..

Comment: don't really understand what you're asking. what do you mean by 'black out the copy'? where does the watermarking come in?

Comment: I thought maybe instead of a repeating watermark script at 5% opacity, I could just do a watermark, black at 100%. In a nutshell, I need a copy of each existing image as a placeholder. (blacked out, grey, etc...). My alternative is probably a PhotoShop action but I know PHP has the ability to create images... I just don't really understand it.

Comment: so you want to make watermarked copies of all your images? a photoshop action would probably be simpler, yes... have you looked into the php gd library? http://php.net/manual/en/image.examples.merged-watermark.php

Comment: Maybe I should just do a copy of each image and apply the IMG_FILTER_BRIGHTNESS to 0 or something for the imagefilter function.